# How do I complete the loop?

Tags: c

I am having trouble figuring out how to get this to run/where to put different equations. The assignment is below the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define OJ 10


//main function
int main () {

    int amount_taken, weight, times_taken, cost_per_oz, num_times;
    float cost_of_container, leftovers, total_cost;

    printf("What is the weight (in oz.) of the original container of OJ?\n");
    scanf("%d", &weight);

    printf("What is the cost of the original container of OJ in dollars?\n");
    scanf("%f", &cost_of_container);

    printf("How many times did your roommate take your juice?\n");
    scanf("%d", &times_taken);
    for(num_times = 0; num_times < times_taken; num_times++) {
.        while ( total_cost <= OJ) {

                printf("How much juice did your roommate take this time (in oz.)?\n");
                scanf("%d", &amount_taken);
                total_cost = cost_per_oz * amount_taken;
                cost_per_oz = cost_of_container / weight;

            if ( total_cost >= OJ) {
                printf("Your roommate owes you $10.00.\n");
                total_cost = total_cost - 10;
            }//if

            printf("How much juice did your roommate take this time (in oz.)?\n");
            scanf("%d", &amount_taken);

        }// while

    } //for

    leftovers = total_cost - 10;
    printf("Your roommate owes you $%.2f.\n", leftovers);

    return 0;
}
```

You and your roommates go through a lot of orange juice.  You've noticed that your roommate goes through more orange juice than you do.  And when they run out, they will take some of yours.

You have been charging your roommate every time they take some of your orange juice.  But it feels a bit silly collecting 50 or 75 cents at a time from them. You’ve come up with a brilliant plan! Instead of charging them every time they take your orange juice, you’ll collect money from them after they have taken 10 dollars’ worth of juice.

Program Setup:

Write a program to mimic this process.  Ask the user to enter the size (in ounces) of the juice containers you buy, as well as the price of those containers (in dollars). Then prompt the user to enter how many times the roommate took juice. Finally, read the amount the roommate took each time. Every time the total value of the juice equals or exceeds $10, print out “Your roommate owes you $10.00.” After all the numbers are entered, if the roommate owes any money, print out the value owed.

Sample Run

```
What is the weight (in oz.) of the original container of OJ?
64
What is the cost of the original container of OJ in dollars?
3.79
How many times did your roommate take your juice?
10
How much juice did your roommate take this time (in oz.)?
30
How much juice did your roommate take this time (in oz.)?
34
How much juice did your roommate take this time (in oz.)?
24
How much juice did your roommate take this time (in oz.)?
40
How much juice did your roommate take this time (in oz.)?
64
Your roommate owes you $10.00.
How much juice did your roommate take this time (in oz.)?
64
How much juice did your roommate take this time (in oz.)?
64
How much juice did your roommate take this time (in oz.)?
18
Your roommate owes you $10.00.
How much juice did your roommate take this time (in oz.)?
20
How much juice did your roommate take this time (in oz.)?
20
Your roommate owes you $2.38.
```

Comment: Begin with initializing `total_cost` before using it and define the function `scan` used in `scan("%d", &amount_taken);` or change it to `scanf`.

Comment: Would this  go in the while statement, inside the for statement,  or outside both?

Comment: it goes at the very beginning, when you declare the variable.

Comment: You need to subtract 10 every time you print "Your roommate owes you $10.00`, not just at the very end.

Comment: Then the leftover will be whatever is still in `total_cost`.

Comment: @MikeCAT Just tell him that `scan()` is a typo, no need to be obnoxious about it.

Comment: Most of your variables need to be `float`, not `int`.

Comment: Thank you! I just edited it but it is still not printing the correct times when the roommate owes $10

Comment: Note that you sometimes use `OJ` (aka `10`) and sometimes write 10 or 10.00.  You should ensure that your code is consistent on that usage so that if the value of OJ changes from 10 to 5 (or to 20), the program remains self-coherent.  It is also not clear that you initialize `total_cost` or `cost_per_oz` properly, especially before the first time through the looping.

Comment: Thank you! I am trying to run it but it won't give me an output of when they owe $10 when it should and still cant get the leftovers right. What should I do? @Barmar

Comment: You still haven't initialized `total_cost` to `0`, and you haven't changed `cost_per_oz` to `float`.

Comment: You don't need the `while (total_cost < OJ)` loop. The `if (total_cost > OJ)` check is sufficient to print the message every time he gets to $10.

Answer (score 1):

Please try if this code can help you. The changes are not very much, and now it seems to print the correct output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#define OJ 10
int main() {
    float amount_taken, weight, cost_per_oz;
    int times_taken, num_times;
    float cost_of_container, total_cost = 0;

    printf("What is the weight (in oz.) of the original container of OJ?\n");
    scanf("%f", &weight);
    printf("What is the cost of the original container of OJ in dollars?\n");
    scanf("%f", &cost_of_container);
    cost_per_oz = cost_of_container/weight;
    printf("How many times did your roommate take your juice?\n");
    scanf("%d", &times_taken);
    for (num_times = 0; num_times < times_taken; num_times++) {
            printf("How much juice did your roommate take this time (in oz.)?\n");
            scanf("%f", &amount_taken);
            total_cost += cost_per_oz * amount_taken;
            if (total_cost >= OJ) {
                printf("Your roommate owes you $10.00.\n");
                total_cost = total_cost - 10;
            }
    }
    printf("Your roommate owes you $%.2f.\n", total_cost);
    return 0;
}
```

Test

```
What is the weight (in oz.) of the original container of OJ?
10
What is the cost of the original container of OJ in dollars?
10
How many times did your roommate take your juice?
3
How much juice did your roommate take this time (in oz.)?
9
How much juice did your roommate take this time (in oz.)?
2
Your roommate owes you $10.00.
How much juice did your roommate take this time (in oz.)?
2
Your roommate owes you $3.00.
```